# wait() on Servlet throws Exception

Tags: java, events, servlets

I'm running a web app in Jboss application server and I'm trying to implement an event base response from the server.

To accomplish that I'm using .wait() and .notify() on the servlets class. Basicly there is an Ajax request, the servlet blocks with `wait` until there is an event on the server and if so `notify` is fired on the servlet.

The problem is when I do wait(1000*60) on the Servlet I get:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet ProcessesServlet threw exception: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
```

Is it even possible to do a wait() on a HttpServlet class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before you wait on an object, you must take ownership.

This is usualy done with a synchronized statement.

```
    synchronized (obj) {
        try {
            obj.wait(someTime);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: and I must do the same before notify?

Comment: [yes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify())

Comment: there's somehting I don't get...if I take ownership with the thread that call .wait by using the synchronized block how can I then take the ownership on the thread that will call .notify. I mean the first synchronized block didn't finish due to the wait statement...correct? Won't there be mutual exclusion?

Comment: Not exactly : "This method causes the current thread (call it T) to place itself in the wait set for this object and then to relinquish any and all synchronization claims on this object"

Answer (score 2):

You can't put wait(...) in servlet because doPost, doGet, ... are not synchronized method.

you can put wait only in synchronized method or block. So you can put a synchronized block and put wait in it.Like below -

```
    synchronized (object) {
        try {
            object.wait(1000*60);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is missing a condition. Whenever you wait, you should always check a condition to protect yourself from spurious wakeup. Basically, wait is guaranteed to return normally in all the cases it says it will. It can also return for no apparent reason. You should follow the pattern from the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29). I wouldn't recommend catching Throwable here or pretty much anywhere. Instead, catch just InterruptedException. Also, you need to make sure that the condition check is thread-safe. So, for instance you could do the following:

```
private boolean condition;
private Object lock = new Object();
private long timeout = 1000;

public void conditionSatisfied() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        condition = true;
        lock.notify();
    }
}

public void awaitCondition() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        while (!condition) {
            try {
                lock.wait(timeout);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Probably throw some application specific exception
            }
        }
        // Perform action appropriate to condition
    }
}
```

You'll notice that you are waiting in a loop. The timeout just means that you wait in intervals of up to the timeout value. If you want to put an overall limit on your wait time, you should note the current time outside the loop and check it after each wait.

Answer (score 1):

As Dystroy said, you need to have a lock on an object to call "wait" on it. If, for some reason, you cannot or do not want to do that (such as the same method running concurrently trying to get a lock on the same object), you can use:

```
try{
    Thread.sleep(time);
} catch (Exception ex){
    Thread.interrupted();
}
```

Or declare a new object on which to obtain a lock.